# Django form: Unique field

Tags: django, django-forms

I have 2 simple form/model classes

```
class Booking(forms.Form):  
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name="Your name*:")  
    place = models.ManyToManyField(Location, blank=True, null=True)

class Location(models.Model):
    place = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

When I display the form I only want to show locations not already previously picked.  The tricky bit (I think) is having the location as `ManytoManyField` as I can't add `unique=True` to it.

So for example user x will pick from a list (London, Cardiff or Edinburgh) and select London.  When user y loads the form London will no longer be available to select.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

How about controlling this at the model level?  Add a BooleanField, called 'inuse', or something similar, to the Location model, and then you can add a filter to your form that only selects the ones that aren't in use.

You would flip inuse to True when User x submits their form...

Also, you could potentially change the relationship to ForeignKey, and then you could use 'unique'

Comment: wow no idea how I would do that.  Would I filter on the model or the view?

Comment: I did it previously in the view.  I had a field in my form called 'coach' and I wanted to populate its drop down with all the users who were in the 'coach' user group I created.  Something like this:  form.fields['coach'].queryset = User.objects.all().filter(groups__name='coach')